# Netlogo: patch size, speed, distance, time

Tags: performance, time, netlogo, distance, patch

I'm trying to figure out how to relate time, distance and speed to my gis-based model's patch size and ticks.

I've got a built model that calculates emissions of different sorts of cars, travelling on different roads at different speeds (from 10 km/h to 120 km/h). My patch size is 50m * 50m. But final information is not adding up with my reporters.

I also know that distance = time * speed. This can be something I can use as input, I think.

So, e.g., when a car travels at 10km/h in 5 ticks, what does that mean? The math I've got on paper tells me that 50m = 10 000 m/h / t h => t= 0.005h => t = 18 seconds to travel 1 tick. So 18*5 = 90 seconds to travel the 250m of the 5 ticks at 10km/h.

Assuming this is correct, how do I code this for my speed range in intervals of 10?

I'm sending section of code I have that I think are pertinent for this:

```
; After setting speed and before moving, calculate distance
    let distance_this_tick speed;; 50 meters per patch
    set distance-traveled distance-traveled + distance_this_tick ;; add the distance to the total

    ; Convert distance traveled to kilometers for reporting
    let distance_traveled_km distance-traveled / 1000
```

(...)

```
to-report calculate-speed [km-per-hour] ; Converts km/h to patches per tick, assuming 1 tick = 1 hour
  report round ((km-per-hour * 1000) / 50)
end

to report-average-distances ; Procedure to compute average distance: for all cars, & by car type
  ;; First calculate the total distance traveled by all cars and the count of cars
  let total_distance_all sum [distance-traveled] of turtles
  let count_all count turtles
  let average_distance_all total_distance_all / count_all

  ;; Convert the total distance to kilometers
  let average_distance_all_km average_distance_all / 1000

  ;; Now calculate the averages for each car type
  let car_typologies ["ev" "combustion-old" "combustion-middle" "combustion-new" "hybrid"]
  foreach car_typologies
  [
    car-typology ->
    let total_distance_type sum [distance-traveled] of turtles with [car-type = car-type]
    let count_type count turtles with [car-type = car-type]
    let average_distance_type 0
    ;; Avoid division by zero if there are no cars of a type
    if count_type > 0
    [
      set average_distance_type total_distance_type / count_type
    ]
    ;; Convert the total distance to kilometers
    let average_distance_type_km average_distance_type / 1000
  ]
end

to-report average-distance-all-cars-km ; Reporters to bring back these measures and show them directly to user in UI:
  let total_distance_all sum [distance-traveled] of turtles
  let count_all count turtles
  ifelse count_all > 0 [
    report (total_distance_all / count_all) / 1000
  ][
    report 0
  ]
end

; The following is a set of 5 reporters that bring back the average distance run by tick for every car:
to-report average-distance-ev-km
  let total_distance_ev sum [distance-traveled] of turtles with [car-type = "ev"]
  let count_ev count turtles with [car-type = "ev"]
  ifelse count_ev > 0
  [
    report (total_distance_ev / count_ev) / 1000
  ]
  [
    report 0
  ]
end
```

... and so on for all the different types of cars I have.

How can I change/update this code to represent my final objective?

Comment: I think you could use a different approach and use the time extension. Like this, you can associate ticks with time (for example, each tick corresponds to 1 second) and give your cars the instructions to move 'x' meters with each tick (if you have all speeds in m/s). Does this make sense to you? I am not sure if I completely understood what your problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes, I ended up doing something like that. I changed the speed  parameters unit to m/s and worked from there. Everything became much easier then. I know the average kms vehicles travel daily and have a counter for that. So, each time the cars average distance reaches the daily average, I have the model stop (which works perfectly for me).